# How to get time zone using moment format

Tags: time, timezone, momentjs, gmt, angular-moment

I need to get the current time zone using moment
i have given my code like this

```
console.log(moment.utc(new Date()).format('Z'),moment.utc(new Date()),'moment')
```

and got the result like

[image]

i would like to get **+0530** but now i'm getting **+00:00**, how can we get that!!

Comment: Simply use [`moment()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/) over [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use [`moment()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/) instead of [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.
>
> This brings us to an interesting feature of Moment.js. UTC mode.
>
> While in UTC mode, all display methods will display in UTC time instead of local time.

See also [Local vs UTC vs Offset](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/) guide.